# How do I dynamically allocate memory to a struct with data?

Tags: c, malloc

Lets say I have a program with a struct

```
typedef struct Room {
      char* name;
      struct Room * North;
      struct Room * South;
      struct Room * East;
      struct Room * West;
      struct Item * itemList;
     char *character[10];
     } Room;
```

And I have to create a bunch of them, as well as dynamically allocate memory for them. As I am new to this, there might be some obvious answers that I might not have known, but how can I assign memory to these structs, while also assigning values to them at once? I know there are ways to do so by declaring a pointer and then manually assigning data using ->, but I want to use the format I have given below, as it would be difficult to assign data one value at a time.

```
  struct Room* room1p = (struct Room*) malloc(sizeof(struct Room));
  struct Room* room2p = (struct Room*) malloc(sizeof(struct Room));
  struct Room* room3p = (struct Room*) malloc(sizeof(struct Room));
  struct Room room1, room2, room3;
  room1 = (Room){roomList[1], NULL, &room3, &room2, NULL, itemRoom1, charList[1]};
  room2 = (Room){roomList[2], NULL, &room2, &room3, &room1, itemRoom2, charList[2]};
  room3 = (Room){roomList[3], NULL, &room1, NULL, &room2, itemRoom3, charList[3]};
```

Comment: The C standard does not provide a facility for both dynamically allocating memory and initializing it, except `calloc`, which clears memory. Write a loop or a function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in way to do this in C. Allocating memory is a separate action from initializing said memory with a value.

You could assign the allocation and initialization to a function if you want to be able to do both in one line:

```
struct Room* room_alloc_and_init(char* name, struct Room* north, 
                                 struct Room* south, struct Room* east,
                                 struct Room* west, struct Item* item_list,
                                 char** character)
{
    // Allocate
    struct Room* new_room = (struct Room*) malloc(sizeof(struct Room));

    // Initialize
    new_room->Name = name;
    new_room->North = north;
    new_room->South = south;
    new_room->East = east;
    new_room->West = west;
    new_room->itemList = item_list;
    new_room->character = character;

    return new_room;
}

// Later on
struct Room* room1 = room_alloc_and_init(...);

// Be sure to free your memory when you are done with it!
free(room1);

// Also free any of the pointers you passed to room_alloc_and_init
// if they point to heap allocated memory
```

Comment: btw, it would be a good practice to code the destructing method alongside with the constructing method, that way memory leaks will be less frequent.

Comment: @yair koskas, good call. I've added a `free()` as a reminder

Comment: Thank you! I am trying it, however, when I type in the line to allocate character data, it says expression must be a modifiable lvalue. Do you know what that means, or how to fix it?

Comment: @sreesh poudyal my bad. Your struct has a pointer to a pointer (a pointer to an array), the function needs to take a `char**` rather than just a `char*`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Also, the function won't "allocate" `character` or any of the North, East, South, West rooms. It will only allocate the Room struct. Your Room struct takes a pointer to those things, so you will need to allocate those and pass their pointers to the function.

Comment: You could write a function that heap allocates them all in one go, I suppose, but you'd need to make a function to free all of those allocations and they'd still be uninitialized.

Comment: Here is a [link to a resource](https://youtu.be/fbYknr-HPYE) to learn a little more about lvalues and rvalues. If you dereference a `char**`, you get a `char*`, which can be assigned so it is an lvalue. Dereferencing a `char*`, however, gives a `char` literal, which is an rvalue. Hence the compiler was complaining about  the `char*` not being a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: boy your life would be a lot easier if you were using c++